# How to freeze columns/rows Markdown Table in README.md file in Github?

Tags: github, layout, markdown, tabular, readme

I know how to create a **Markdown Table** in  `README.md` file in [`Github`](https://github.com/)
Something like that

```
|   FREEZ   |   col1    |   col2    |   col3    |   col4    |
|   ----    |   ----    |   ----    |   ----    |   ----    |
|   row1    |   ----    |   ----    |   ----    |   ----    |
|   row2    |   ----    |   ----    |   ----    |   ----    |
|   row3    |   ----    |   ----    |   ----    |   ----    |
|   row4    |   ----    |   ----    |   ----    |   ----    |
```

My question
Anyway How to freeze column/rows
So the scrolling will not move freezed cells

Comment: Don't think that's possible.

Comment: If something like that was possible it would require custom CSS and/or JavaScript and GitHub would never allow  user provided custom CSS/JavaScript on their site. Therefore, this is not possible on GitHub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After deep investigation and search
We can say that, till now `Jan 2019`
**No, Its not possible**